# Reverse for 'update_task' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update/(?P<update>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am building a small CRUD project and stuck on a very basic thing which is an update. First I found it
on stack overflow, google and Facebook as well but couldn't be able to find the solution so finally
posting my problem here will all code.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, HttpResponseRedirect

from .models import Task

from .forms import TaskForm

def tasks(request):
    task = Task.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    context = {
        'forms': form,
        'tasks': task
    }
    return render(request, 'task/task.html', context)


def update_task(request, update):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=update)
    form = TaskForm(instance=task)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {
    'form': form
}
    return render(request, 'task/update_task.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import tasks, update_task

urlpatterns = [
    path('', tasks, name='tasks'),
    path('update/<str:update>/', update_task, name='update_task'),
]
```

I am facing a problem in this section of update_task.html.

my update_task.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'update_task' form.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
```

tasks.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ToDo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mystyles.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>ToDo App</h1>
<form class="" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="input">
    {{ forms }}
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</div>
</form>

{% for task in tasks %}
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="">
    {{ forloop.counter }} - {{ task }}
    <a class="btn btn-info" type="button" href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Update</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `form.id` will be empty or `None`

Comment: in update_task.html?

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass task id for `GET` method

so try this way

```
def update_task(request, update):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=update)
    form = TaskForm(instance=task)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print("==",form.errors)
    context = {
    'form': form,
    'task': task
    }
    return render(request, 'task/update_task.html', context)
```

*update_task.html*

```
<form action="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: well bro it worked but problem is that it is not updating the task.

Comment: and please can you tell that ho task.id is applied in update_task.html?

Comment: [05/Oct/2020 09:16:54] "GET /update/10/ HTTP/1.1" 200 704

Comment: this is what i am getting

Comment: name 'p' is not defined

Comment: Exception Location: C:\Users\Royal\PycharmProject\todoapp\todoapp\task\views.py, line 27, in update_task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222505/discussion-between-pruthvi-barot-and-muhammad-abubakar).

Comment: [05/Oct/2020 09:21:31] "GET /update/10/ HTTP/1.1" 200 704